# Issue link magento with vuestorefront

Tags: magento2, vue-storefront

I have a store built with Magento Ver.-2.4.3-p1 and
I am trying to replace the front end with VueStorefront 2.
But when i'm trying to connect the VueStorefont 2 with my current Magento system i'm facing this issue

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Cannot query field "payment_payflowpro_cc_vault_active" on type "StoreConfig"., Location: [column: 5, line: 45], Path: undefined
```

Note: I have tried to connect Vuestorefront with a fresh version of Magento and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed, as it was a required GraphQL item which is requires another module.